# Text wrap nightmare in PHP after PREG_REPLACE

Tags: php, word-wrap

Provinces is a group_concat of all the individual records that contain province, some of which are blank.
So, when I encode:

> ```
> $provinces = ($row['provinces']);
>
> echo "<td>".wordwrap($provinces, 35, "<br />")."</td>";
> ```

This is what the result looks like:

> Minas Gerais,,,Rio Grande do
>
> Sul,Santa Catarina,Paraná,São Paulo

However, when I try to preg_replace out some of the nulls, and add some spaces with this expression:

> $provinces = preg_replace($patterns,
>   $replaces, ($row['provinces']));

```
echo "<td>".wordwrap($provinces, 35, "<br />")."</td>";`
```

This is what I get!!! :(

> Minas Gerais, Rio Grande do
>
> Sul, Santa
>
> Catarina, Paraná, São Paulo

The output is very unnatural looking.

BTW: Here are the search and replace arrays:

```
$patterns[0] = '/,,([,]+)?/';       $replaces[0] = ',&nbsp;';
$patterns[1] = '/^,/';              $replaces[1] = '';
$patterns[2] = '/,$/';              $replaces[2] = '';
$patterns[3] = '/\b,\b/';           $replaces[3] = ',&nbsp;';
$patterns[4] = '/\s,/';             $replaces[4] = ',&nbsp;';
```

UPDATE: I even tried to change Paraná to Parana

> Minas Gerais, Rio Grande do
>
> Sul, Santa
>
> Catarina, Parana, São
>
> Paulo

Comment: So what exactly are you asking? also is there a reason you are using '&nbsp;' in your replaces versus just a regular space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `&nbsp;` as the replacement. `wordwrap()` considers that 6 characters. It doesn't interpret the HTML entity. That's why your lines are breaking funny. If you want `&nbsp;` replace spaces after you `wordwrap()`

Also, your first pattern should be:

```
// match one or more commas together
$patterns[0] = '/,+/';
```

Comment: Actually, &nbsp; is six characters.

Comment: @webbiedave, you count better than me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is the `wordwrap()` really necessary? It sounds like you are rendering this content into a table cell of some fixed width and you don't want individual entries to split across lines.

If this inference is correct - and if none of your entries is actually so long that forcing it to a single line will break your layout - then how about this: `explode()` on commas into an array, remove the whitespace-only entries, replace normal spaces in each array entry with `&nbsp;`, and `implode()` back on `,` (a comma followed by a space). Then let the rendering browser break lines wherever it needs.